# One row test insertion to SQL Server RDS works but full load times out

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a Glue job script that does this (not showing imports and setup here) and it inserts the row into SQL Server RDS just fine:

```
columns = ['test']
vals = [("test")]

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
test = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "test")
datasink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = test, 
database = "database-name", table_name = "table-name")
job.commit()
```

When I run with this same connection but for a larger test load (ends up being about 100 rows) I get this error:

> An error occurred while calling o596.pyWriteDynamicFrame. The TCP/IP connection to the host , port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall

The thing is that I know there's no firewall or security group issue since one row inserts just fine. I've tried adding a loginTimeout parameter to the JDBC connection like so:

`jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:<port>;databaseName=dbName;loginTimeout=600;`

As it indicates you can do so [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/working-with-a-connection?view=sql-server-2017). But the connection fails with Glue when I do that but succeeds when I remove the loginTimeout parameter.

I've also checked the remote timeout configuration on my SQL Server instance and it shows as 600 seconds which is longer than any of my failed jobs so it couldn't be that.

How can I get around this connection timeout error? It seems to be a limitation built into Glue.

Comment: Have you checked if your `IAM` role and permission policy if JDBCis correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do a JDBC connection with Glue you need to follow the steps in this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-glue-access.html

We had done that but it turns out that our self-referencing sec group wasn't actually self-referencing. Once we changed that it got resolved

I also had to create the connection as an Amazon RDS connection and not as a JDBC connection even though it's doing the same thing under the hood.

Even after doing all that I still had issues. Turns out that you need to add the sql connection specifically to the job outside of the script. If you hit "Edit Job" you'll see a list of sql connections there. If the connection you're trying to hit isn't on the list of required connections you will always timeout